# I'm trying to find a way to loop through a series of numbers until all the numbers in the list are the same as the last number before a missing or NA

Tags: r, loops, nested, na

Let's use these numbers as an example because I can't share the actual data end=c(1,3,6,NA,6,7,8,NA,12,23,NA). I need to convert this to end=c(6,6,6,NA,8,8,8,NA,23,23,NA).

```
`repeat{
  end[k]=end[k+1]
  k=k+1
  if(is.na(end[k+1]) | k==length(end)){
    
    break
  }
}`
```

I've tried this as a first step but I'm stuck in how to loop through this while eventually skipping over the NA. I've tried adding this loop approach to it but it doesn't give me the desired output.

```
`j=1
while (j <= length(end)){
k <- j
repeat{
  end[k]=end[k+1]
  k=k+1
  if(is.na(end[k+1]) | k==length(end)){
    
    break
  }
}
 j=j+1
}`
```

Does anyone know how to loop through these numbers while temporaliy stopping the loop at an NA and converting the last number before the NA to all the previous numbers.

Answer (score 4):

### Solution

Replace the values between NAs with the value that comes before each NA. This is the fastest solution (check out the benchmark).

```
na_pos <- which(is.na(end))
end[-na_pos] <- rep(end[na_pos-1], diff(c(0,na_pos))-1)
end
#> [1]  6  6  6 NA  8  8  8 NA 23 23 NA
```

If `end` doesn't end with an NA, the solution wouldn't work. So just to be safe you can modify it this way:

```
na_pos <- union(which(is.na(end)), length(end)+1)
end[-na_pos] <- rep(end[na_pos-1], diff(c(0,na_pos))-1)
end
#> [1]  6  6  6 NA  8  8  8 NA 23 23 NA
```

With a really minor slow down, it's still the fastest solution.

### Solution with a FOR loop

Just to help you, I'll leave here a working for loop solution.
You go from the end to the beginning and when you get and you replace any NA value with the previous non NA value.

```
for(i in seq(length(end), 2)){
  
  if(!is.na(end[i]) & !is.na(end[i-1])) end[i-1] <- end[i]
  
}
end
#> [1]  6  6  6 NA  8  8  8 NA 23 23 NA
```

### Benchmark

It this example the `napos` method is by far the fastest method. I took the liberty to compare with the other solutions too.

```r
library(dplyr)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  
  napos = {
    end <- c(1,3,6,NA,6,7,8,NA,12,23,NA)
    na_pos <- union(which(is.na(end)), length(end)+1)
    end[-na_pos] <- rep(end[na_pos-1], diff(c(0,na_pos))-1)},
  
  forloop = {
    end <- c(1,3,6,NA,6,7,8,NA,12,23,NA)
    for(i in seq(length(end), 2)){

      if(!is.na(end[i]) & !is.na(end[i-1])) end[i-1] <- end[i]

    }
  },
  cumsum = {
    end <- c(1,3,6,NA,6,7,8,NA,12,23,NA)
    grp <- cumsum(is.na(end))
    end <- ave(end, grp, FUN=function(x) ifelse(!is.na(x), tail(x, 1), NA))
  },
  
  rle = {
    
    end <- c(1,3,6,NA,6,7,8,NA,12,23,NA)
    end <- ave(end, 
        with(rle(is.na(end)), rep(seq_along(values), lengths)),
        FUN = function(x) tail(x, 1))
  },
  
  dplyr = {
  
    end <- tibble(end = c(1,3,6,NA,6,7,8,NA,12,23,NA)) |> 
      mutate(
        section = if_else(is.na(end), NA_integer_, cumsum(is.na(end)))
      ) |> 
      group_by(section) |> 
      mutate(
        end = tail(end, 1) # or alternatively last element
      ) |> 
      pull(end)
})
#> Unit: microseconds
#>     expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
#>    napos    23.4    41.65    63.071    64.25    77.70   133.0   100
#>  forloop  5430.0  6154.35  7307.699  6729.85  7359.55 15330.1   100
#>   cumsum    98.5   143.40   227.069   195.55   254.00  2614.1   100
#>      rle   134.3   192.05   270.753   259.20   291.65  1964.7   100
#>    dplyr 13386.2 14998.55 16530.285 15647.60 16779.35 40551.9   100
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Using base R we can use `cumsum` with `is.na` to define a "group" or a run of values. Then we can use `ave()` to transform values within those groups just keeping the last value and preserving NA values

```
grp <- cumsum(is.na(end))
ave(end, grp, FUN=function(x) ifelse(!is.na(x), tail(x, 1), NA))
#  [1]  6  6  6 NA  8  8  8 NA 23 23 NA
```

This returns the desired result with out an explicit loop.

Answer (score 0):

A variation on the answer from @MrFlick could be:

```
ave(end, 
    with(rle(is.na(end)), rep(seq_along(values), lengths)),
    FUN = function(x) tail(x, 1))

 [1]  6  6  6 NA  8  8  8 NA 23 23 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea using dplyr.
First create groups, then use them to extract the desired number.

```
library(tidyverse)

data <-
  tibble(end = c(1,3,6,NA,6,7,8,NA,12,23,NA)) |> 
  mutate(
    section = if_else(is.na(end), NA, cumsum(is.na(end)))
  )

data2 <- 
  data |> 
  group_by(section) |> 
  mutate(
    end2 = max(end), # use maximum
    end3 = tail(end, 1) # or alternatively last element
  )
```